# How can I restart my program (8086 TASM)

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

In the end of my program I have an option to restart the program.

To perform this option, I need to reset some of my variables to ensure that there will not be any problems.

I want to ask if there is an interrupt or function (or else) that will be able to restart/reload the program?

If it was not clear, I'm using DOS OS (on dosbox).

Comment: I am learning the 8086 assembly. That's why I'm using dos. Also, I don't think that your question is relevant to my question.

Comment: No it is actually not relevant, except because you're using DOS in 2014. I'm pointing that you're using an extremely outdated and useless technology that won't add any benefits to you, in fact probably the opposite. And I don't know where you got that but you don't need DOS to learn 8086 assembly.

Comment: I have to use dos because I learn 8086 in school and there they are teaching 8086 with dos (don't ask me why). I know it is not a relevant technology, but I still learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your program once more as child process (dont forget to reduce memory allocated by current process before running child process).

Comment: Is there an easy way to reduce memory allocated by my current program if I'm using preallocated data segment?

Comment: Relocate stack and small code segment near PSP and mark all memory above it as free by editing MCB at (PSP-1):0.

Comment: I don't think there are child processes in MS-DOS. It's a single process OS.

Comment: And 8086 does not even have support for multiprocesses.

Comment: @m0skit0 - INT 21H Function 4BH - Execute program

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it will be much easier for me to reset the necessary variables in my program than messing with the MCB while I don't know about a lot (only by researching a little in the internet).
But yet, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any [DOS system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API) to restart a program, the same way there's no such system call even in modern OSs (AFAIK, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I saw the ms-dos api in Wikipedia before asking this question. From my experience, sometimes there are interrupts that are not part of the ms-dos interrupts but yet can do some useful functions. That's why I asked this question. I'll wait for another person to approve your answer, and if so I'll accept it.

Comment: From my 15 years experience, I've never seen such *reset* function in DOS or any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple reseting the start values of some variables stored in a the data segment without terminating and restarting the program.

```
Numberone = 1
Numbertwo = 2
Numberthree = 3

VALUE1 DD Numberone
VALUE2 DD Numbertwo
VALUE3 DD Numberthree

mov DWORD PTR[VALUE1], Numberone
mov DWORD PTR[VALUE2], Numbertwo
mov DWORD PTR[VALUE3], Numberthree
```

With terminating and restarting the program:
Like "Egor Skriptunoff" said with the "INT 21H Function 4B00H" it is possible to load, start and execute a programm as a child, so we can build with it a program that can start and  also restart other .exe or .com programs, like one part of a file commander clone.

If the child program terminate with an errorlevel byte placed in the AL-Register for signaling for to restart with our own special value, then the mother program can check it (like within a batchfile) and can restart the program soon again, indirect controlled by the child program.

Ralf Browns interrupt list(RBIL): inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.G

```
--------D-214B-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 2+ - "EXEC" - LOAD AND/OR EXECUTE PROGRAM
AH = 4Bh
AL = type of load
    00h load and execute
    01h load but do not execute
    03h load overlay (see #01591)
    04h load and execute in background (European MS-DOS 4.0 only)
    "Exec & Go" (see also AH=80h)
DS:DX -> ASCIZ program name (must include extension)
ES:BX -> parameter block (see #01590,#01591,#01592)
CX = mode (subfunction 04h only)
    0000h child placed in zombie mode after termination
    0001h child's return code discarded on termination
Return: CF clear if successful
    BX,DX destroyed

...cut...

Format of EXEC parameter block for AL=00h,01h,04h:
Offset  Size    Description (Table 01590)
 00h    WORD    segment of environment to copy for child process (copy caller's
      environment if 0000h)
 02h    DWORD   pointer to command tail to be copied into child's PSP
 06h    DWORD   pointer to first FCB to be copied into child's PSP
 0Ah    DWORD   pointer to second FCB to be copied into child's PSP
 0Eh    DWORD   (AL=01h) will hold subprogram's initial SS:SP on return
 12h    DWORD   (AL=01h) will hold entry point (CS:IP) on return
SeeAlso: #01591,#01592
```

Example of a parameter block:

```
PARBLOCK  equ THIS WORD      ; parameter-block for the EXEC-Function
          DW 0               ; same environment-block
          DW OFFSET COMLINE  ; Offset-address and
          DW SEG COD         ;  segmentaddress of the command line
          DD 0               ; no date in PSP #1
          DD 0               ; no data in PSP #2
COMLINE   DB 80h dup (0)     ; command line
```

Hint: We have to save the addresses of the SS and SP register pair into two reserved words in our codesegment of our mother program before calling this interrupt. So if the child was normaly terminated we can get back our stack pointer to the mother program.